# Lock or disable resizing of task bar autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, taskbar

As the title says, is there a way to lock or disbale resizing of taskbar through AHK scripting? without using mouse commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F1::
PostMessage, 0x111, 424, 0,, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm

`0x111` being `WM_COMMAND` with `424` being the message number

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14380/Manipulating-The-Windows-Taskbar